# Interval Notation for Integrals?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Doing homework, I came across a question like the following:
$$
\int_{[-1,1]\times[0,1]}\sin(x^2y^3)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.
$$
I am having trouble understanding what the notation means? Does it simply represent
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^2y^3)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy?
$$

I am assuming this is referring to set notation?

Comment: Almost, except the intervals are reversed from the variables they belong to.

Comment: interval notation indeed. But I would guess $[-1,1]$ is for $x$, not for $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, the notation $A\times B$ represents the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), which is defined as
$$
A\times B=\{(a,b)\mid a\in A\ {\mbox{ and }}\ b\in B\}.
$$
So for your problem,
$$
[-1,1]\times [0,1]=\{(x,y)\mid x\in [-1,1]\ {\mbox{ and }}\ y\in [0,1]\},
$$
which leads us to write
$$
\iint_{[-1,1]\times[0,1]}(\cdots)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy
=\int_0^1\int_{-1}^1(\cdots)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Kind of. The integral over $[-1, 1] \times [0, 1]$ is a double integral, which has an analogues definition to the ordinary integral, though it uses partitions consisting of 2D regions rather than subintervals, but by Fubini's Theorem, it is *equal* to the iterated integral you suggest (if you calculate the integrals in the right order).